# Setting dirAllowed to false in Jetty 8.1.12

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty

I was using Jetty 6.x where we created a spring based Jetty server with dirAllowed set to false.
The config is as follows.

```
<bean id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectors">
        <list>
            <bean id="Connector" class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <property name="port" value="${tnplportal.jettyServer.httpPort}" />
                <property name="headerBufferSize" value="${tnplportal.jettyServer.headerBufferSize}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="handler">
        <bean id="handlers" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <property name="handlers">
                <list>
                    <bean id="contexts" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
                        <property name="handlers">
                            <list>
                                <bean class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                                        <property name="contextPath" value="/fileServer" />
                                        <property name="resourceBase" value="ResourcePath" />
                                        <property name="initParams">
                                            <map> 
                                               <entry key="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed" value="false" />
                                            </map>
                                        </property>
                                </bean>

                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now I am upgrading to Jetty 8.1.12 and found that initParams is not available for org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.Now present config is below (with dirAllowed commented out)

```
    <bean id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectors">
        <list>
            <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <property name="port" value="${tnplportal.jettyServer.httpPort}" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="handler">
        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <property name="handlers">
                <list>
                    <bean id="contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection">
                        <property name="handlers">
                            <list>
                                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                                    <property name="contextPath" value="/fileServer" />
                                    <property name="resourceBase" value="resourcePath" />
                                    <!-- <property name="initParams">
                                           <map>               
                                            <entry key="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed" value="false" />
                                           </map>
                                        </property> -->
                                </bean>

                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can someone tell me how to set dirAllowed property for Jetty 8.1.12

I saw few posts for code based servers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217969/how-to-disable-directory-listing-for-jettys-webappcontext)

But my server is spring based. How do I set with spring based configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade from Jetty 6 to Jetty 8 requires you to update your Jetty references.

To start with, you'll need to update *all* of your named classes.  The project moved to the Eclipse Foundation 6 years ago, this resulted in a mandatory package name change from `org.mortbay.jetty` to `org.eclipse.jetty`

Then you'll want to update the various setters to be relevant to what you are attempting to do.

Would recommend that you grab a copy of the [Jetty Distribution tarball (or zip)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/) and check out the Jetty XML files that it comes with for some inspiration, while also referencing the [Jetty 8 Javadocs](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-8/apidocs/) for some details.

*Note: Jetty 6 was EOL'd in 2010.  [Jetty 8 is EOL at the end of 2014](https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-announce/msg00069.html), there will be no more updates to Jetty 8 after this year.  Would highly encourage that you upgrade all the way to Jetty 9 now.*

Comment: If you see the code snippet I have attached, I have done all necessary changes to upgrade to Jetty 8 and I am able to launch the application without any trouble. Only issue here is to set dirAllowed(to avoid listing of files from browser). I am not sure how to set that in Jetty 8.

Answer (score 0):

An temp workaround should be create a custom WebAppContext, it's not grace but works.

```
public class CustomWebAppContext  extends org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext{
  public void setInitParams(Map<String, String> values){
    Map<String, String> currectParams= getInitParams();
    if(currectParams==null){
        currectParams= new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : values.entrySet()){
        currectParams.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}}
```

Then in xml :

```
      <bean class="CustomWebAppContext">
                                    <property name="contextPath" value="/fileServer" />
                                    <property name="resourceBase" value="ResourcePath" />
                                    <property name="initParams">
                                        <map> 
                                           <entry key="org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed" value="false" />
                                        </map>
                                    </property>
                            </bean>
```