# Disable directory listing in jetty

Tags: webserver, jetty

I am using jetty to deploy my web application. I have changed the `webdefault.xml` `dirAllowed` parameter to `false`, still jetty is listing all the contexts path inside it whenever I will give IP:PORT.

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Jetty are you using? I am unable to replicate this on 9.4.3 in either the webdefault.xml or by implementing it in the web.xml for a specific webapp.

Comment: @Walkerwatch I am using 9.4.3 version. Downloaded from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-home/9.4.3.v20170317/jetty-home-9.4.3.v20170317.tar.gz . I am using jetty docker image.

Comment: The page contains the following information   :                                         Error 404 - Not Found.
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:

    /UserManagement ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@887af79{/UserManagement,file:///tmp/jetty/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-UserManagement.war-_UserManagement-any-2467051063966033581.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{/UserManagement.war}

Comment: The error you've given another issue entirely. You originally stated that you were able to deploy the web app and navigate to it's root but that the directory listing was appearing. What you indicated in your latest message is that the webapp/context is not available at all. Could you clarify what problem is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify the `webdefault.xml` directly, you have to provide your own copy of it, and specify its location in your context xml deployable `${jetty.base}/webapps/UserManagement.xml`.

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
                           "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure id="testWebapp" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <Set name="contextPath">/UserManagement</Set>
  <Set name="war">
    <Property name="jetty.webapps"/>/UserManagement.war
  </Set>

  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor">
    <Property name="jetty.base"/>/etc/mywebdefault.xml
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

A simpler solution is to modify your `WEB-INF/web.xml` in your `UserManagement.war` as outlined in the previous answer ...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43328817/775715

Comment: I updated my UserManagement.xml and now it's not listing the war files present inside webapps folder. Thank you joakim