# Serve a list of files in a directory by just specifying the directory URL in Jetty

Tags: java, jetty

Is it possible to serve files in a given directory using jetty by just providing the directory URL ?

I have a directory called "dist" and it contains five jar files. Is it possible to serve all five jar files by just providing the dist folder in the URL like http://localhost:8000/dist ?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Meisch, I don't have code yet. Before writing the code, I want to make sure my requirement is feasible hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the feature you said is "Directory Listing". It can be enabled/disabled by:

```
webAppContext.setInitParameter("org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.Default.dirAllowed", "true");
```

or

${JETTY_HOME}/etc/webdefault.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>dirAllowed</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

See also:
[How to disable directory listing for Jetty's WebAppContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217969/how-to-disable-directory-listing-for-jettys-webappcontext)

Jetty documentation:
http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/advanced-extras.html